# React-Native-Web not compiling react native components from node module dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to convert my react-native app to react-native-web. I have followed [this](https://medium.com/@jonnykalambay/your-first-hybrid-app-in-15-minutes-react-native-on-the-web-2cc2646051e) reference. Following are the steps I followed:

1. Created RN application and run it on iOS to check to confirm it is working on mobile.
2. Executed following command:
   `npm install react-scripts react-dom react-native-web react-art react-router-native react-router-dom`
3. Created `index.html` file in public directory.
4. Created `index.js` file in src directory with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

5. Added following scripts in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "web": "react-scripts start",
    "build-web": "react-scripts build"
  },
```

6. Executed application in web by running `npm run web` and my app was running in web browser.

Everything worked only till I was not using any 3rd party module for my app. (Though styles weren't yet working :P)

Now, I installed the `react-native-snap-carousel` library and I found that `react-native-web` is only working for the react-native components created in my project's `src` directory and not working for `nodeModules` code. Since simply render from `node module` with the following code fails:

```
render() {
  return <View></View>
}
```

with following error:

```
./node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/carousel/Carousel.js
SyntaxError: /Users/kapil.choubisa/Kapil_Data/JPPL/Code/POCs/IMMobileWeb/node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/carousel/Carousel.js: Unexpected token (1223:12)

  1221 | 
  1222 |         return (
> 1223 |             <View></View>
```